# Working on a desktop from a laptop

Tags: asp.net, networking

I have an older desktop computer that I want to use for web development. But I don't want to connect a screen, keyboard and mouse to work directly on the desktop. I would rather want to work wireless from my laptop computer. Thus, I want to be able to start Visual Studio on my desktop but I want to do it from my laptop.

How do I do?

Comment: Sorry - this is totally off-topic here. You should use programmers.stackexchange.com for such questions....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is set up a remote desktop connection between your desktop and laptop. The instructions to do so vary from windows version to windows version, so a good google search looking up 'remote desktop connection' will give you good instructions

Comment: Read the FAQs, and for questions that are so clearly off-topic, don't even bother answering.